# Should COHESIVE MECHANISMS use INTENTION-REVEALING INTERFACE of the core domain or the generic concepts encapsulated?

Tags: domain-driven-design

In the blue book chapter 15 "Distillation", Eric Evans talk about a pattern he calls Cohesive Mechanisms. In that chapter many times is said that the capabilities of the framework should be exposed with an Intention-Revealing Interface (chapter 10). For instance, I quote from [DDD Reference](https://domainlanguage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DDD_Reference_2015-03.pdf):

> Partition a conceptually cohesive mechanism into a separate lightweight framework. Particularly watch for formalisms or well-documented categories of algorithms. Expose the capabilities of the framework with an intention-revealing interface. Now the other elements of the domain can focus on expressing the problem ("what"), delegating the intricacies of the solution ("how") to the framework.

The example given in the book is about a subset of a graph traversal framework implemented as a cohesive mechanism, encapsulating the algorithms needed to perform the computations that would muddied the domain, which is about an organizational chart and not graph theory. The framework is exposed with an intention-revealing interface, Eric says, but I'm confused if that interface uses the language of the domain, the organizational chart, or instead is an intention-revealing interface that talks the language of graph theory.

I have my own example in a software I'm working on. It needs to create a set of documents, with somewhat elaborated rules and validations, that users will print. The implementation of the domain model talks about the concepts in those documents and tries to express the rules in the cleaner way we can achieve (constant improvement here). Every document has an id number with domain meaning, but as long as an user is working in the draft of those documents, the numbers can be rearranged and discarded based on some rules, until the draft is "accepted" as valid. The computations needed to rearrange the numbers are a little complicated and convoluted, obscuring the model that is not about numbers itself (even though the calculations are important).

I feel that this is a good case to apply the pattern, so we can test the "framework" in isolation to validate the intricate computations and at the same time we free the rest of model from the clutter they produce.

So the question is:

**When the book talks about the pattern an says it should be exposed with a intention-revealing interface, Does that interface talk the language of the model the computation was extracted from (organizational chart; documents and rules), or does it talk the language of the mechanism itself (graph theory; numbers and rearrangement)?**

Of course pragmatism should not be forgotten and we'll test some options, keeping the one that looks cleaner and performs the job well; however as I was reading the chapter in the search of inspiration the question bothers me and I couldn't answer it from the text (or I'm not looking at the right place).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything that prevents you from using technical terminology.  In fact, I would argue that we are going to implement many bits of the domain for purely technical reasons and as long as they make sense and map/relate to something in the UL we should be OK.

If there is some form of business language that makes your intention revealing interface explicit then go with that; else I would opt for whatever technical term most accurately describes what you intend to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cohesive mechanism should use the Math/Generic terminology (which is not technical) otherwise it is not very useful.
In my article https://link.medium.com/r5OMHq6sCxb, I gave an example of a cohesive mechanism implementation.